# How to populate a variable based on another variable's value

Tags: r

I have a data frame where solution has different constituents of an overall entity. A value of 0 means it doesn't have this constituent and a value of 1 means it does have this constituent. If there are more than one constituents (i.e. more than one solution value = 1), then overall = "more than one" and the individual constituents are decoded in the decoded variables.

```
df1 <- data.frame (solution0 = "0", solution1 = "1", solution2 = "0", solution3 = "1",  overall = "more than one", decoded0 = "", decoded1 = "aluminum", decoded2 = "", decoded3 = "hydrogen")
```

If only one solution = 1 (i.e. only one constituent), then that constituent is mapped to overall and the decoded variables are blank ,as in the two following examples:

```
df2 <-  data.frame (solution0 = "0", solution1 = "1", solution2 = "0", solution3 = "0",  overall = "aluminum", decoded0 = "", decoded1 = "", decoded2 = "", decoded3 = "")
```

```
df3 <-  data.frame (solution0 = "0", solution1 = "0", solution2 = "0", solution3 = "1",  overall = "hydrogen", decoded0 = "", decoded1 = "", decoded2 = "", decoded3 = "")
```

What I have so far:

```
df1$overall <- case_when(
  sum(df1$solution0 + df1$solution1 + df1$solution2 + df1$solution3) > 1 ~ 'more than one',
  TRUE ~ ''
)

df1$decoded0 <- ifelse(df1$solution0 == "1" & sum(df1$solution0 + df1$solution1 + df1$solution2 + df1$solution3) > 1, "lithium", "")

df1$decoded1 <- ifelse(df1$solution1 == "1" & sum(df1$solution0 + df1$solution1 + df1$solution2 + df1$solution3) > 1, "aluminum", "")

df1$decoded2 <- ifelse(df1$solution2 == "1" & sum(df1$solution0 + df1$solution1 + df1$solution2 + df1$solution3) > 1, "sodium", "")

df1$decoded3 <- ifelse(df1$solution3 == "1" & sum(df1$solution0 + df1$solution1 + df1$solution2 + df1$solution3) > 1, "hydrogen", "")
```

I don't know how to program the logic "If only one solution = 1 (i.e. only one constituent) and the rest are = 0, then that constituent with = 1 is mapped to overall" into the first case_when statement.

Comment: I am confused. What is your input `df1`, `df2`,`df3` or all of them and what is your expected output?

Comment: df1, df2, and df3 are my expected outputs but I want to know how to code the variables overall and decoded, which are based on the solution variables. So the raw data would just be solution0 - 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate row-wise sum for columns that start with `"solution"` and assign values to `overall` column.

```
library(dplyr)

apply_fun <- function(df) {

  df %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(rs = rowSums(select(., starts_with('solution'))), 
           overall = case_when(rs > 1 ~ 'more than one', 
                               solution0 == 1~ "lithium",
                               solution1 == 1~ "aluminum",
                               solution2 == 1~ "sodium",
                               solution3 == 1~ "hydrogen",
                               TRUE ~ '')) %>%
   select(-rs)
}
```

We can pass dataframe to the above function.

```
apply_fun(df1)
#  solution0 solution1 solution2 solution3       overall decoded0 decoded1 decoded2 decoded3
#1         0         1         0         1 more than one       NA aluminum       NA hydrogen

apply_fun(df2)
#  solution0 solution1 solution2 solution3   overall decoded0 decoded1 decoded2 decoded3
#1         0         1         0         0  aluminum          NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: Thanks. When rs = 1, how do I map the decoded value of the solution to the variable overall? For example, solution1 = "lithium", solution2 = "aluminum", solution3 = "sodium" and solution 4 = hydrogen". If solution1 = 1 and the rest = 0, overall should be equal to "lithium" because 1 means this entity is present while 0 means this entity is absent. If solution2 = 1 and the rest of the solutions = 0, then I want overall to equal "aluminum". Does this make sense? Thanks.